# calling Python function on Button Click event

Tags: python

I have`Post Request` method that returns a list of numbers `obj_list` from the client side whenever a button is clicked. in the below py function i've defined `obj_db` to store the **multiplication** of `obj_list` .

How do i go about whenever the button is clicked again , the initial results in `obj_db` gets add (**sum**) with  the results of`obj_list` after **multiplication** . ?

Here's the code i've tried :

```
# if i press a button on the client side, 
#(obj_list) returns something like this [0.3, 2.32, 1.22],which  i get via post method successfully . 

if request.method == 'POST':  
    x = 1
    obj_db = []
    for obj_items in obj_list:     
         should_sum  = False
         while not should_sum:
             x *= obj_items
             #return only two decimal numbers after float number  
             new_obj_num  = round(obj_total, 2)
             obj_db.append(new_obj_num)
             print('stored value  : ', obj_db)
            if object_selected:
              obj_db += obj_items
            else:
              should_sum = True
```

Comment: Hi! Could you share a little bit more of code? Right now, what I see is that your js file is doing a post request but in your python file you are trying to read a form but without knowing how you get the forms parameter loaded in the request it's difficult to know what's wrong.

Comment: @Gabo just shared the code , there is no problem on getting data through post  request . i updated the question now

Comment: You need to save the counter value somewhere before answering the browser its request. You can save it in a database if the user is identified somehow. You can save it in a class attribute if you're using class views, but it's not recommended since it will be reset after reseting the server. Or you can return the counter value in your answer so the browser can re-send it to you on next click.

Comment: @Gabo do you have a code sample for that , the problem here is not the counter , if the button is clicked twice need to multiply , and sum with the previous data returned

Comment: Ok. then you need to store the previous data returned. If it's a small project and it's only meant for one user, try using a file to store the previous data so you can get it on next request to be used

Comment: @Gabo this is exactly where the issue exists, i've tried that but with no luck, if you can perhaps ellaborate with code that would be better. -- this part is only a small part of the project, there is no multiple users . Just need  to deal with the button clicks when pressed for the first time and for the 2nd, 3rd ... Times .

Answer (score 1):

As we talked in the comments you need to save your counter to know how many times anyone clicked.

```
# try to read the counter stored in a file 
try:
    f = open("counter.txt", "r")
    data_returned_as_str = f.read()
    counter = int(data_returned_as_str)
except FileNotFoundError as e:
     counter = 0 

# do your stuff

counter += 1
f = open("counter.txt", "w") # use write to overwrite the last content
f.write(str(counter))
f.close()

print(counter)
```

If you also need the previous data write another file to read that.

Comment: i've tried to refactor your answer to suit my need, but nothing. the main issue is when button is pressed once, second, third ....

Comment: Please describe fully what's going on so I can help you. Edit your answer to describe in pseudocode what you're trying to do if you need to.